# Scan via the browser?

Tags: html, scanning

Is it possible to trigger an image scan using a scanner and upload the result via js using the latest modern browsers (Chrome & Firefox)?

Searching google doesn't seem to provide anything useful.

Comment: What do you mean by image scan? Scan from where?

Comment: you can use `getUserMedia` API to receive data from your camera, and _scan_ things. If that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use a commercial product, [scanner.js](http://asprise.com/document-scan-upload-image-browser/direct-to-server-php-asp.net-overview.html) does scan documents and upload images from browsers like IE, Chrome and Firefox to web servers.

[Try the live demo here](http://asprise.com/document-scan-upload-image-browser/javascript-web-scanner.js-demos.html)

*Disclaimer: I an am employee of Asprise which offers the above mentioned product.*